How to return type from variable in TS
class A {

  public static find(): Query{
      const f = () => new this();
      return new Query(f);
  }

}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

class Query {

    private readonly entity: () => A;

    constructor(entity: () => A) {
        this.entity = entity
    }

    public someMethod():???? {
       return this.entity()
    }
}

It is something like a part of ActiveRecords. I can't understand how to specify return type for Query.someMethod(). I can specify it as A because it is parent of all classes, but in this case I can not use child class as type, for example:
const monkey: C = C.find().someMethod()

this will produce type error
new in TypeScript, please, answer carefully and soft

Sounds like you are looking for generics

I'd say you want Query to be generic (and probably need find() to be generic also, although since it's static you have to jump through hoops as per ms/TS#5863).  See this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks @bergi. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks @jcalz. This is exactly what I'm looking for.

If you want a Query to keep track of which subclass of A it's holding, then you should make the class generic in the type T of that subclass (constrained to A):
class Query<T extends A> {

    private readonly entity: () => T;

    constructor(entity: () => T) {
        this.entity = entity
    }

    public someMethod(): T {
        return this.entity()
    }
}

You also want A.find() to be similarly generic so that it returns something like Query<this> using the polymorphic this type so that B.find() returns Query<B> and C.find() returns Query<C>.  Unfortunately find is static and TypeScript does not directly support this types in static members.  See microsoft/TypeScript#5863.
Luckily there's a workaround (as mentioned in that issue) where you make the method generic and use a this parameter instead:
class A {
    public static find<T extends A>(this: new () => T): Query<T> {
        const f = () => new this();
        return new Query(f);
    }
}

That means when you call find(), TypeScript will only allow you do so if the object on which you call it is of type new () => T (a constructor) for some T constrained to A. Let's test it out:
class B extends A { ⋯ }
const qb = B.find();
//    ^? const qb: Query<B>
const b = qb.someMethod();
//    ^? const b: B

class C extends A { ⋯ }
const qc = C.find();
//    ^? const qc: Query<C>
const c = qc.someMethod();
//    ^? const c: C

Looks good.
Playground link to code
